# How to show only current month and previews month's dates selectable in datePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datetimepicker, datetimeformatinfo

Show Only Current and previous month in date picker dialog.

```
  datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(DateConvertActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    String s = "" + dayOfMonth + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year;
                    edtDate.setText(s);
            }
      }, mDay, mMonth, mYear);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution. It's from first day of previous month to this day.

**In Kotlin:**

```
private fun setupUi() {
    // Get calendar instance
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    // Get current time
    val currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    // Create listener
    val listener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, day ->
        // Show Toast after selection
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected: $day.$month.$year", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    // Max = current
    val maxTime = calendar.timeInMillis

    // Move day as first day of the month
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    // Move "month" for previous one
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1)

    // Min = time after changes
    val minTime = calendar.timeInMillis

    // Create dialog
    val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        this,
        listener,
        currentYear,
        currentMonth,
        currentDay
    ).apply {
        // Set dates
        datePicker.maxDate = maxTime
        datePicker.minDate = minTime
    }

    // Show dialog
    datePickerDialog.show()
}
```

**And in Java:**

```
private void setupUi() {
    // Get calendar instance
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Get current time
    int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create listener
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Show Toast after selection
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("Selected: %s.%s.%s", day, month, year), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    // Max = current
    long maxTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    // Move day as first day of the month
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    // Move "month" for previous one
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

    // Min = time after changes
    long minTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    // Create dialog
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
            this,
            listener,
            currentYear,
            currentMonth,
            currentDay
    );

    // Set dates
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxTime);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minTime);

    // Show dialog
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

If you need WHOLE current month (from first to last day) you can replace par with this **Kotlin code**:

```
// Move day as first day of the month
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
// Move "month" for previous one
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1)

// Min = time after changes
val minTime = calendar.timeInMillis


// Move day as first day of the month
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
// Move to next month
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, +2)
// Go back one day (so last day of current month)
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)

// Max = current
val maxTime = calendar.timeInMillis
```

**and in Java:**

```
// Move day as first day of the month
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
// Move "month" for previous one
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

// Min = time after changes
long minTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

// Move day as first day of the month
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
// Move to next month
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, +2);
// Go back one day (so last day of current month)
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

// Max = current
long maxTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 3):

Pick the date in Timestamp see below code

```
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Then convert `tsLong` to any specific format and extract the one you need.

For Reference: [Android TimeStamp](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Comment: This isn't working. It only shows the current date and next to any.